# Can't get the first method name in a multicast delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have this code:

```
public void AddMenuRow(FuncInvoker i_FuncToAdd)   //  add a row to menu.
{
    if (d_Lines == null)
    {
        d_Lines = new FuncInvoker(i_FuncToAdd);
    }
    else
    {
        d_Lines += i_FuncToAdd;
    }
}
```

for adding methods to the invoke list.

And now I want to print the name of each method to the console, so I made this:

```
public void Show()
{
    int count = 1;
    string name = null;

    Console.WriteLine(m_Title);
    foreach (FuncInvoker list in d_Lines.GetInvocationList())
    {
        name = list.Method.Name;
        Console.WriteLine((count++) + ". " + name);
    }
}
```

The problem is in the first method name, which always prints "invoke" for some reason.
The next methods in the delegate link work fine.

Can someone help me with this? I have tried everything.

Comment: This approach will have issues if you ever decide to localize your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
d_Lines = new FuncInvoker(i_FuncToAdd);
```

...you're actually creating a *new* delegate instance that wraps the original delegate. The method-target of this new delegate will be the `Invoke` method of the original delegate (assuming it's unicast), which explains the behaviour you're observing.

The obvious workaround is to not use a wrapper and just copy a reference to the original delegate to the variable:

```
d_Lines = i_FuncToAdd;
```

But you might as well  do away with your 'special-case' branch completely and just do (assuming the argument can't be `null`):

```
public void AddMenuRow(FuncInvoker i_FuncToAdd)                    
{
    d_Lines += i_FuncToAdd;
}
```

This will work fine since [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c.aspx) (which is what the `+=` syntax becomes) is speced to return a reference to the second delegate if the first delegate is `null`, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: wow!! that it?! thanks a lot i really got stucked with that :)

Comment: The only thing to note is that the first approach modifies the original delegate, which means that adding the same "menu item" to diffrent menus.might not work. Damn Android keyboard. :-)

Comment: @moshe: I am pretty sure that a simple `List` would suit the job of **storing a list of items** better than a multicast delegate. I think you chose the wrong tool.